# css padding, position text in the upper center of a web sit

Tags: html, css

I am writing a website in Html using CSS; in my website I have a text logo that I want to place in the top center size of the site, I am using CSS as indicated below

```
background-color:#4d5152; 
position:fixed;
width:970px;
top: 0%;
padding-right:200px;
padding-left:200px;
```

My question is, how can I position my logo in the upper center and have the left and right size of the logo the same color of the logo without righting the values to the padding left and right; so it will be generic for all computer monitor size and browsers 
hope I am clear enough
Thank for the help

Comment: is your logo in a div? Put you HTML and CSS here.

Comment: no it is in the Html page covered by the CSS

Comment: You should learn more about `HTML` with `TAG` of `HTML`. And should learn more about `CSS` with `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I would write something like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">        
        <h1 id="logo">My Company</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width:960px; /* Width of the containing 'wrapper' or content area */
    margin:0 auto; /* This will center the wrapper. 0px margin on the top and bottom, and 'auto' on the left and right (let the browser decide the amount of margin). */
}

h1#logo {
    text-align:center; /* If you don't define a width the h1 will be 100% as its parent (#wrapper). This centers the text.  */
}
```

Here's an example showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/V5Cff/1/embedded/result/